# closure - but still not the current var

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem.. When I alert a var/obj (fields) I don't get the right one returned

Have tried to solve it with a closure, but still the same..

Outside the click() the current and right object (fields) is returned, but not inside

---

## EDIT: jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/CfxLx/

### have now made a jsfiddle.. when you want to edit a row and afterwards want to save it, the alertbox returns the id from the row you last pressed edit

---

```
this.insert_actions = function(row, id, table, elm, fields, options){
        var actions = $('<div class="actions"></div>').appendTo(elm);

        var _this = this;

        if(options.edit){
            alertobj(fields); // alerts object

            var btn_send = $('<input class="btn btn_margin_top" type="button" value="'+Lang.get('BTN_SAVE')+'" />').appendTo(actions)
                .click(function(){
                    alertobj(fields); // alerts object
                });

                ....
```

## with closure

```
this.insert_actions = function(row, id, table, elm, fields, options){
        var actions = $('<div class="actions"></div>').appendTo(elm);

        var _this = this;

        if(options.edit){
            alertobj(fields); // alerts object

            var btn_send = null;
            (function(fields){
                btn_send = $('<input class="btn btn_margin_top" type="button" value="'+Lang.get('BTN_SAVE')+'" />').appendTo(actions)
                    .click(function(){
                        alertobj(fields); // alerts object
                    });
            })(fields);

            ....
```

## the complete function

```
this.insert_actions = function(row, id, table, elm, fields, options){
    var actions = $('<div class="actions"></div>').appendTo(elm);

    if(options.edit){
        alert(fields.account_id_.dom.val());
        var btn_send = $('<input class="btn btn_margin_top" type="button" value="'+Lang.get('BTN_SAVE')+'" />').appendTo(actions)
            .click(function(){
                alert(fields.account_id_.dom.val());
                _this.put_row({
                    id : id
                }, {
                    index : row.index(),
                    insert : true
                }, table, row, fields);
            });

        var btn_cancel = $('<input class="btn btn_light btn_margin_top" type="button" value="'+Lang.get('BTN_CANCEL')+'" />').appendTo(actions)
            .click(function(){
                _this.get_rows({
                    id : id
                }, {
                    index : row.index()
                }, table, row);
            });

        var Tab = new Tabindex();

        for(var key in fields){
            (function(key){
                Tab.add(key, fields[key]);
                fields[key].dom.keydown(function(e){
                    if(Detect_key.get_keyname(e) == 'ENTER'){
                        btn_send.click();
                    }
                    else if(Detect_key.get_keyname(e) == 'ESC'){
                        btn_cancel.click();

                        return false;
                    }

                    return Tab.press(key, e);
                });
            })(key);
        }
    }
    else{
        var btn_edit = $('<input class="btn" type="button" value="'+Lang.get('BTN_EDIT')+'" />').appendTo(actions)
            .click(function(){
                _this.get_rows({
                    id : id
                }, {
                    index : row.index(),
                    edit : true
                }, table, row, fields);
            });

        var btn_delete = $('<input class="btn btn_light" type="button" value="'+Lang.get('BTN_DELETE')+'" />').appendTo(actions)
            .click(function(){
                Dialog.set_dialog({
                    headline : Lang.get('HDL_DELETE'),
                    body : Lang.get('DLG_DELETE_ACCOUNT'),
                    btns : [
                        {
                            value : Lang.get('BTN_DELETE'),
                            func : function(){
                                var A = new Ajax();
                                A.url = 'json.action.php?action=delete_'+table;
                                A.data = {
                                    id : id
                                };
                                A.success = function(response){
                                    if(response.error){
                                        var Cnt = new Content();
                                        Dialog.set_error({
                                            body : Cnt.error_body(response.error),
                                            btns : [
                                                {
                                                    value : Lang.get('BTN_OK'),
                                                    func : function(){
                                                        Dialog.rmv_error();
                                                    },
                                                    focus : true
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        });
                                    }
                                    else{
                                        row.remove();
                                        Dialog.rmv_dialog();
                                    }
                                };
                                A.send();
                            },
                            focus : true
                        },
                        {
                            value : Lang.get('BTN_CANCEL'),
                            func : function(){
                                Dialog.rmv_dialog();
                            },
                            type : 'light'
                        }
                    ]
                });
            });

        actions.css({
            opacity : 0
        });

        row.mouseover(function(){
            actions.fadeTo(0, 1);
        })
        .mouseout(function(){
            actions.fadeTo(0, 0);
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: First, you tried to use an *immediate function* to solve the problem, not a closure (although it is a closure too). And second, you don't need one here, because you are not in a loop. If it does not alert the right values then because you are calling the function with the wrong arguments (or you are changing the object somehow in the part you did not show).

Comment: the right object is alerted outside the click()

Comment: @clarkk: Then please provide a minimal working example at http://jsfiddle.net/.

Comment: @clarkk: Felix is right about the code you've quoted. The problem must lie elsewhere, probably in something you've omitted for simplicity.

Comment: have now added the complete function... later I will make a jsfiddle :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely problem I can see is this line, from `append_rows`:

```
var curr_fields = fields;
```

It seems like you're expecting this to make a copy of `fields`, however this is not what actually happens. JavaScript objects are effectively passed "by reference", so when you assign the value of `fields` to `curr_fields`, you're giving *two names* to *one object*.

An example case:

```
var a = { name: "foo" };
var b = a;
b.name = "bar";
alert(a.name); // Shows "bar"
```

A closure might let you use the *same name* over again in another iteration of a loop, but it will never give you another copy of the *same object*.

Javascript doesn't provide any built in way to do a "deep copy", which you'd need to get a full copy of your multi-level nested `fields` object. Fortunately jQuery does, with the [`extend`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) method, using the `deep` parameter.

This means you can get everything working by replacing the line with this:

```
var curr_fields = $.extend(true, {}, fields);
```

What this does is starts with a new object (the `{}` in the middle parameter), and then jQuery goes through every object and property in `fields` and duplicates it into the new object, which is then stored in `curr_fields`.